# Process Cannot Access the File Attachment

Tags: c#, file, file-io, attachment

I have the following code (or the equivalent thereof):

```
var provider = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataStreamProvider([...]);
try
{
    if (provider.FileData.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (System.Net.Http.MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
            Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);

            AddAttachment(file.LocalFileName, file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", ""));

            if (attachmentPaths.Length != 0)
            {
                attachmentPaths += ";";
            }
            attachmentPaths += file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ ... }

...
public void AddAttachment(string attachmentFileName, string attachmentName)
{
    var AttachmentList = new List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>();

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment newAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentFileName);
    newAttachment.Name = attachmentName;
    AttachmentList.Add(newAttachment);
}
```

And I'm getting the "Process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process" error. I'd just like to know where my application could be getting the error. I can't tell where in here it is actually trying to access the file. My best guess is in the Attachment constructor, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Side note: I don't know how to trigger it. It's happening during a nightly e-mailing process and I see the error in our logs. I'd rather not make any changes to the program other than fixing it to handle the error better. That is to say, I don't think I can debug it.

Comment: It is a pretty normal mishap.  Could be because you have a bug in your program and you don't close/dispose the file.  Could be because some other process is also has the file open, just like the exception says.  Could be because anti-malware blocks access until it is done scanning the file.  It is entirely up to you to narrow it down.  Generating a loud alert so you can quickly inspect the machine is surely necessary to get ahead.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Hans. I understand that the file is being used by something else. What I don't understand is where I'm trying to access it in the code above. So far as I can tell, it's not doing any reads, writes, or deletes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a way to test it in a debugger. And the answer was yes, the System.Net.Mail.Attachment constructor is what was trying to access the file.